# System Notifications at WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, notifications

How I can attach `click` event to a button at system toast notifications on WPF application using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications library?

I know that I need to use `IBackground` interface but I can't tie to this class, because the following code is causing the error ( `ToastNotificationActionTrigger()` element not found, HRESULT: 0x80070490) .

```
        private void RegisterBackgroundTask()
        {
        const string taskName = "ToastBackgroundTask";
        // Otherwise create the background task
        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
        builder.Name = taskName;
        builder.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(ToastNotificationBackgroundTask).FullName;
        // And set the toast action trigger
        builder.SetTrigger(new ToastNotificationActionTrigger());
        // And register the task
        builder.Register();
        }
```

The view of my notification:

[image: View of my notification]

Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

I used notifications in WPF a year ago, here is how I achieved it:

First you have to add from Nuget the package [Windows API Code Pack](https://github.com/aybe/Windows-API-Code-Pack-1.1).

Then I used the following code:

```
public static void RaiseGeneratedNotification(int errors, int warnings)
{
    // Get a toast XML template
    XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText04);

    // Fill in the text elements
    XmlNodeList stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
    stringElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("Web Studio"));
    stringElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(Strings.Errors+": "+errors));
    stringElements[2].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(Strings.Warnings+": " +warnings));


    // Specify the absolute path to an image
    String imagePath = "file:///" + Path.GetFullPath("App.png");
    XmlNodeList imageElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
    imageElements[0].Attributes.GetNamedItem("src").NodeValue = imagePath;

    // Create the toast and attach event listeners
    ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml)
    {
        ExpirationTime = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(2)
    };

    // Show the toast. Be sure to specify the AppUserModelId on your application's shortcut!
    ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(Resources.AppId).Show(toast);
}
```

With this code I did the following steps:

1. Get the notification template.
2. Get the fields of the notification
3. Fill the fields
4. Create a notification with the template
5. Raise the notification

You also have to register an AppId in your application shortcut.

I hope this can help you.

Comment: thanks, @ganchito55 , i already now how to show simple system notification with text, description and image, but now I want to realize notification with buttons. I used the [following article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tiles_and_toasts/2015/07/08/quickstart-sending-a-local-toast-notification-and-handling-activations-from-it-windows-10/), but I can`t handle click button event.

Comment: @VitaliiKulyk I have just followed that article, and in a new WPF application I have the error that ToastNotification isn't recognised. Can you send me a project with your code? I will try to fix it.

Comment: mr @ganchito55, you can download my project clicking on the [link](https://github.com/vitcool/WPFDesctopNotifications/tree/master/CSharp-Toast-Example). I will appreciate any help.

Comment: @VitaliiKulyk I have analyzed your project and I am come to the conclusion that the problem is that you are using UWP notifications in WPF app, so the problem is that some components are unavailable. The tutorial that you are following is for UWP not for WPF apps.

Comment: mr @ganchito55, you can see UWP notifications in my project (both with button as without it),  but you can`t handle click button event, that is strange, in my opinion, and I need to find solution of this problem.